# Creating a flexible contact database in Javascript - adding, deleting and finding contacts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with building a contact database.
It is a single page, that opens in the browser, where the user can create new contacts, delete contacts, and use a search bar to find existing contacts. Each contact should have a name, surname, phone number, and address. I already managed to code the first part (creating new contacts in a database), but am struggling with the second and third part (deleting and finding contacts from or in the database).

My Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var database = [];

$('.newContact').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var user = {};
user.firstName = $('.firstName').val();
user.surname = $('.surname').val();
user.phoneNumber = $('.phoneNumber').val();
user.address = $('.address').val();


database.push(user);
console.log(database);

});
});
```

My html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">  

<head>
  <title>Codeworks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <h1>Start of coding assignment</h1>
  </header>

  <main>

    <div class="introduction">
      <h2> What is the assignment? </h2> 
      <div class="introtext">Build a simple address book application using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery. It is a single page, that opens in the browser, where the user can create new contacts delete                              contacts, and use a search bar to find existing contacts. Each contact should have a name, surname, phone number, and address.<br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="introduction">
          <h2> Create a new contact </h2> 
          <div class="introtext">Please fill in the name, surname, phone number and address in each grid below.<br> </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form>
       Name:
      <input class="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"> <br>

       Surname:
      <input class="surname" type="text" name="surname" id="surname"> <br>

      Phone Number:
      <input class="phoneNumber" type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber"> <br>

      Address:
      <input class="address" type="text" name="address" id="address"> <br>

      <button class='newContact' type="submit">Create new contact now!</button>   
      </form>
    </div>


<div class="introduction">
          <h2> Deleting a contact </h2> 
          <div class="introtext">Please fill in the name and surname of the person you would like to remove.<br>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form>
      <label for="First name"> Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"> <br>

      <label for="Surname"> Surname: </label>
      <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"> <br>

      <button class='deleteContact' type="submit">Remove contact now!</button>
      </form>
    </div>  



 <div class="introduction">
          <h2> Searching a contact </h2> 
          <div class="introtext">Please fill in the name and surname of the person you would like to search.<br>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form action='' method='get'>
      <label for="Search"> Name: </label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"> <br>

      <label for="Surname"> Surname: </label>
      <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"> <br>

      <button class='searchContact' type="submit">Search contact now!</button>

      <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src='script.js'> </script>



      <div id='result'>TEXT</div>  

  </main>
<footer>   
  <h1>End of Coding assignment</h1>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

How should I do this?

Full code here: https://w.trhou.se/e2dgpkyskk

Comment: You tried something to solve this? Your database is a simple array. you can search in it via the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and remove elements with [one of them](https://hosting.review/tutorial/javascript-remove-element-from-array/)

Answer (score 0):

So I looked through your code, and I think you need to focus on step 3 first: finding contacts - if you want to delete a contact, you need to find that contact first anyway, right? So let's focus on the first part.

You have this function here:

```
function findUser(firstName, surname) {
    return database.find(u => database.user.firstName == deleteUserFirstName && database.user.surname == deleteUserSurname);
}
```

And while you're on the right track, you're missing the mark just a little. The `find` method takes a function as a parameter, applies that function to *each item in the array*, and returns the first item in your array that makes it return `true` (doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)). Your variable `database` is an array of `user` objects, and your goal is to find the first one that has the given first and last name, correct? So then, the function above should be rewritten as:

```
function findUser(firstName, surname) {
    return database.find(user => user.firstName == firstName && user.surname == surname);
}
```

Now, this function will take whichever `firstName` and `surname` you give it and find it in the database. You are able to find a user, step 3 complete! Step 2 is now a breeze - you can use this new and improved function to find a user for deletion:

```
$('.deleteContact').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var deleteUserFirstName = $('.firstName').val();
    var deleteUserSurname = $('.surname').val();

    var userToDelete = findUser(deleteUserFirstName, deleteUserSurname);
    const index = array.indexOf(userToDelete);
    if (index > -1) {
        database.splice(index, 1);
    }  
});
```

This finds the index of the found `user` and then removes them from `database`. There are a few things you can do to clean up and refactor your code (for example I recommend not leaving the code in the anonymous function like that but creating a proper function for deleting a user and calling that instead) but that can be addressed once it's working since it seems like this is for an assignment and you're running out of time.

Answer (score 0):

https://w.trhou.se/yttkvhfnpc

I reworked my html and js code and was wondering if you could take another look? I think I made decent progress. Can you spot the remaining errors?

A few specific questions:
1) How can I make sure that array is defined?
2)The delete and find function don't seem to work yet. What is wrong?

Ideally I would have to find the answer by this evening European time...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">  

<head>
  <title>Codeworks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <h1>Start of coding assignment</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="introduction">
      <h2> What is the assignment? </h2> 
        <div class="introtext">
          Build a simple address book application using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery. <br>
          It is a single page, that opens in the browser, where the user can create new contacts delete  contacts, and use a search bar to find existing contacts.<br> 
          Each contact should have a name, surname, phone number, and address.<br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="introduction">
       <h2> Create a new contact </h2> 
          <div class="introtext">
            Please fill in the name, surname, phone number and address of the person you would like to add in each grid below and press "Create new contact now".<br> 
            Please fill in the name and surname of the person you would like to remove and press "Remove contact now".<br>
            Please fill in the name and surname of the person you would like to search and press "search contact now".<br>     
          </div>
    </div>

    <form>
       Name: <input class="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"> <br>
       Surname: <input class="surname" type="text" name="surname" id="surname"> <br>
       Phone Number: <input class="phoneNumber" type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber"> <br>
       Address: <input class="address" type="text" name="address" id="address"> <br>

      <button class='newContact' type="submit">Create new contact now!</button>   
      <button class='deleteContact' type="submit">Remove contact now!</button>
      <button class='searchContact' type="submit">Search contact now!</button>
    </form>

      <div id='result'>TEXT</div>  

  </main>
<footer>   
  <h1>End of Coding assignment</h1>
</footer>
       <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src='script.js'> </script>


</body>

</html>
```

---

```
var database = [];

$(document).ready(function() {


$('.newContact').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var user = {};
user.firstName = $('.firstName').val();
user.surname = $('.surname').val();
user.phoneNumber = $('.phoneNumber').val();
user.address = $('.address').val();


database.push(user);
console.log(database);

});
});

function findUser(firstName, surname) {
    return database.find(user => user.firstName == firstName && user.surname == surname);
}

$('.searchContact').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var findUserFirstName = $('.firstName').val();
    var findUserSurname = $('.surname').val();
    var userFound = findUser(findUserFirstName,findUserSurname);  
    $('#result').text(userFound);
});


$('.deleteContact').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var deleteUserFirstName = $('.firstName').val();
    var deleteUserSurname = $('.surname').val();

    var array = [];
    var userToDelete = findUser(deleteUserFirstName, deleteUserSurname);
    const index = array.indexOf(userToDelete);
    if (index > -1) {
        database.splice(index, 1);
    }  
});
```